# Why do I see a message SQUASHFS ERROR:UNABLE TO READ DATA AND PAGE WHILE INSTALLING UBUNTU

Tags: 20.04

Since 2days onwards iam unable to install ubuntu on my windows 10 
i am trying to install 20.04 version of ubuntu its appearing like this
SQUASHFS ERROR:UNABLE TO READ DATA AND PAGE

Answer (score 7):

Your ISO was either corrupted, or your write to install media was flawed. Other reasons for it are the install media is faulty etc, but in my experience it's the write to install media most at fault.

Did you verify your ISO after download and before write to media?

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Assuming you trust your installation media, the write is the most common faulty flaw in my experience, so I write it again (if it fails again, using another box or to different media).  Either way first step is the validate your ISO following the tutorial.

FYI:  For faulty installation media, you'll see messages like the following in logs, these are the result of what I'm describing:

```
Jun 26 10:37:24 ubuntu kernel: [  363.074612] SQUASHFS error: zlib decompression failed, data probably corrupt
Jun 26 10:37:24 ubuntu kernel: [  363.074615] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x76d9b3d5
```

*If you file a bug report with these messages, you'll either get a response telling you what I've said here, or your report will be marked a duplicate of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1874662  (which you can read for other wording)*

Comment: FYI: The bot no longer *dups* error reports to the bug report I mentioned; and hasn't for a long time...  Error checking by the bot has been improved and it rejects now with other messages.