# Errno5 - input/output error

Tags: system-installation, 20.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 in a virtual machine. I got the error as installation crashed if I skip.

```
The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:

[Errno 5] Input/output error

This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk.  
It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed,   
to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from  
electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and in   
need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.
```

I tried reinstalling and also have checked the RAM. It's all fine. I increased the RAM to 4GB and also 25GB storage. I also tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 and had the same issue.

Comment: Your ISO or install media appears to be faulty; did you validate it?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0  The CD/DVD refers to whatever install media you are using (be it hdd/sdd/thumb-drive/ISO on file-system/cd/dvd...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I see a message SQUASHFS ERROR:UNABLE TO READ DATA AND PAGE WHILE INSTALLING UBUNTU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236021/why-do-i-see-a-message-squashfs-errorunable-to-read-data-and-page-while-install)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)