# SQUASHFS error: How to poweroff laptop?

Tags: boot, usb, battery

I created a bootable USB with Ubuntu 20.04 on it and I wanted to test it on a working Ubuntu 20.04 Laptop whether it works. This was apparently not a good idea, because I get dozens of SQUASHFS-errors and I cannot do anything at the moment (I pressed the on-off-button several times, but the laptop still won't turn off). I am pretty sure by now (since I already removed the flash drive and checked it on another computer) that the flash drive is corrupted.

This is not a huge problem, what does annoy me is that I cannot use my laptop. I cannot take the battery from the notebook (it isn't removable), so what can I do (it probably still has around 5 - 10 hours battery life-time, and I wouldn't mind having my laptop soon)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I see a message SQUASHFS ERROR:UNABLE TO READ DATA AND PAGE WHILE INSTALLING UBUNTU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236021/why-do-i-see-a-message-squashfs-errorunable-to-read-data-and-page-while-install)

Comment: The best way to force shutdown in my opinion is via keyboard commands directly to the kernel (ie. SysRq keys)

Comment: @guiverc I am afraid that giving keyboard commands directly to the kernel is not possible (nothing happens when I type "SysRq", for instance).

Comment: Alt-SysRq followed by letters (SysRq is a key on the keyboard (also usually same key as PrintScreen; SysRq with Alt usually, some laptops require a Fn key combination). To reboot it's Alt+SysRq (holding down Alt) then followed by REISUB - ie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key or other resource)

Comment: @guiverc Thanks! It was Alt + SysRq + b for me that changed the state of the kernel!! If you write your comment as an answer, I will immediately accept it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell the kernel to reboot you can use

ALT+SysRq REISUB
*continue holding down ALT key as you type all letters*

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) the REISUB the the kernel

> ```
> unRaw (take control of keyboard back from X),
> tErminate (send SIGTERM to all processes, allowing them to terminate gracefully),
> kIll (send SIGKILL to all processes except init, forcing them to terminate immediately),
> Sync (flush data to disk),
> Unmount (remount all filesystems read-only),
> reBoot.
> ```

To shutdown the machine instead of reboot, you can replace the B with a "O".  All keystrokes are worth it to ensure a clean system (`sync` or flush buffers to disk & `umount` protecting data on your system prior to reboot or power-off.   SysRq keys are far safer than trying to use the power-off or pulling a power cable on a box as the kernel can cleanly shutdown the system (*or obey other commands, refer wikipedia page for clues*)

PS: I'd not recommend the Alt-SysRq + B as it won't leave a clean *file system*; REISUB is safer.

Comment: Okay, then there is sth I must ask: What is "REISUB"? Is it really the key-combination of "R" + "E" etc.?

Comment: REISUB are the keys you press whilst still holding down the ALT key, after hitting SysRq.  R kills X, E asks all processes to die gracefully etc (see question or wikipedia link I like) The S & U are what I consider essential, but prior keys help S & U to work (ie processes are killed allowing sync & umount)  You don't hit all keys at the same time, one after the other whilst holding down ALT.  ps: the wikipedia article has some ways to and help you remember REISUB (like *every good boy deserves fruit* is taught learning to play piano/organ etc)