# The installer encountered an error copying to the hard disc errno5 - input/output error

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, xubuntu, lubuntu

I am new to the Linux OS. Following [this tutorial](https://www.lifewire.com/install-ubuntu-linux-windows-10-steps-2202108) I was able to successfully install VirtualBox-6.1.12 boot it directly from my windows 10 computer and then Ubuntu-20.04.1, and I used the Ubuntu successfully in following tutorials in a linux-based training I am undergoing. I did not install or launch any item from an external device such as a pen drive, CD or DVD. At some point the Linux machine became so slow and I decided to uninstall and reinstall the VirtualBox (from Windows 10 control panel) and follow the tutorial again to reinstall Ubuntu on the VirtualBox. After several attempts, this second process reinstallation of Ubuntu stops at various levels of the tutorial and without success.

In one of the stages where it stops, for example during the execution of step 21 of the tutorial, an unmodifiable form appears in whose fields I can type in nothing[image: an unmodifiable form]

Then shortly afterwards [image: this error message appears]

In cases, where I go pass stage 21, I get the error message [image: I get the error message]

This last point is the furthest I have gotten since the start of my attempts to reinstall.

Can someone please hint me?

Comment: Please edit your question and add which version of Ubuntu you are trying to install. Also add links to screenshots, in imgur.com, of exact before the crash and after. So that we know at what point the crash occurs.

Comment: The error I see is a *squashfs* error, I'd switch and confirm via logs, which means the ISO is corrupted & you didn't validate it usually (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)  or it was badly written to your install media & you failed to validate the write to your media/  The CD/DVD refers to your install media (regardless of the media it's stored on, ie. cd, dvd, flash-card, thumb-drive, disk, ssd, hdd or ISO itself is corrupted & squashfs checksum checks)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I see a message SQUASHFS ERROR:UNABLE TO READ DATA AND PAGE WHILE INSTALLING UBUNTU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236021/why-do-i-see-a-message-squashfs-errorunable-to-read-data-and-page-while-install)

Comment: I don't know if you have virtualbox booting from a thumb-drive, cd, dvd etc (most of the time we just point it to the ISO itself & skip the write to media), but did you check the ISO as being valid/non-corrupted?   In my *duplicate* post the message I use is from logs; ie. I `dmesg |grep squashfs` which should only show the program version message(s), but also highlights errors which only occur on bad media or invalid/corrupted ISO.  Also note if you have insufficient RAM in your VM, you can cause *squashfs* errors too; so check you've allocated the VM enough ram.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu)