# Loading Kernel from GNU GRUB v2.04

Tags: grub2, bash, kernel

I was running Ubuntu LTS 20 on a HP Spectre laptop. I was reinstalling Ubuntu 20 by erasing the current Ubuntu and all the files, midway through the installation, I received an error saying the files on the bootable USB had been corrupted. The laptop restarted and now I'm facing a GRUB screen. I have tried loading the kernel but I cannot seem to find the vmlinux file anywhere.

Comment: Please clarify your release. Desktop and server releases use a *yy.mm* format for releases, *yy* being used only by *snap* based specialist releases which are different products to the *yy.mm* releases.  It sounds like you've either an invalid ISO (did you verify it?) or the write to your installation media was faulty (was that verified?), but starting with your release will help, Ubuntu has had *yy* format release since 2016, such as Ubuntu Core 20 (with 10 years of supported life)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I see a message SQUASHFS ERROR:UNABLE TO READ DATA AND PAGE WHILE INSTALLING UBUNTU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236021/why-do-i-see-a-message-squashfs-errorunable-to-read-data-and-page-while-install)