# Ubuntu server failing to install on chromebook motherboard

Tags: server, system-installation, chromebook

First of all to start this off... I AM VERY NEW TO THIS!  I have experience in many other aspects of computers but this is my first dive into the linux system.

my end goal is to install Octoprint (3d printer utility) onto ubuntu server so I can wirelessly control my printer.  I am using a gutted chromebook motherboard for this.  It has a Intel® Celeron® Processor N3160 with 32GB emmc.

So now where the problems begin- I used mrchromebox to put a custom “bootloader?” on the board.  I slapped an image of Ubuntu server 20.04.2 and started going through the process.  Right when I reach the end, and try to install it onto the emmc it says it fails. [error message?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g27BM.jpg)

There there is also a point in the initial verification where it says it found 1 error.  I downloaded a new image and tried reflashing the sd card multiple times without any change
[verification error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ExLz.jpg)

Any help assistance would be great, I’ve tried this with gallium OS and it worked fine, although that’s an operating system specifically created around these types of laptops.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I see a message SQUASHFS ERROR:UNABLE TO READ DATA AND PAGE WHILE INSTALLING UBUNTU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236021/why-do-i-see-a-message-squashfs-errorunable-to-read-data-and-page-while-install)

Comment: If it fails to verify, the installation media is flawed and thus problems can occur, and the installation should not be trusted until manually verified as being trustworthy (a far slower process than just re-writing media & re-installing many times over).  You can also get *squashfs* errors or failures to verify if your box doesn't have sufficient RAM or other virtual conditions, but in my experience it's mostly the write to your installation media assuming you verified the ISO prior to write to your media.

Comment: Who knows, I tried using it ubuntu desktop and it worked fine for some reason...  I just ended up using debian

Comment: The "errors found in 1 files! You might encounter errors" means a prior user step was invalid & needed to be done correctly...   most common cause as I stated is a faulty write to media (or invalid ISO)...   That is a user-procedure which needed to be fixed by the user/operator   (*bad luck* can play a part as flash-drives are not quality media, being built to price without validation found on more expensive media like ssd/hdd/etc)

Answer (score 0):

I know that you are looking to get Ubuntu Server installed on your Chromebook, but I found an article on How-to Geek that goes through the process of installing Ubuntu DESKTOP (with the lightweight XFCE desktop environment) alongside ChromeOS. Click [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/) to read.

By the way, you can use a Ubuntu Desktop installation interchangeably as a Ubuntu Server installation (and vice-versa). In fact (at least as far as I know), the only difference between the Desktop and Server editions of Ubuntu is the packages that ship with them by default. For example, regular Ubuntu Desktop comes with the GNOME Desktop environment. Ubuntu Server does not. Otherwise (as far as I know) they're twins. You can definitely install packages designed for servers on a Ubuntu Desktop installation. Same as how you can install a desktop environment on a Ubuntu Server installation. Also (at least as far as I know), you can take any tutorial written for Ubuntu Server, and apply it to a Ubuntu Desktop installation by using the terminal to run commands (but not vice-versa, since Ubuntu Server only ships with a CLI).

Comment: Ok so I never got ubuntu server to work, but for some reason the desktop version worked fine?...  I just ended up using debian lol