# Error 5 - input/output error

Tags: administration

I am trying to install Ubuntu (actually Kubuntu, but I've tried Ubuntu as well and it gives the same error) on my AMD Ryzen 5 3500u laptop, which runs windows perfectly. Every time I try to install Ubuntu or Ubuntu-based distros, setup just throw me that error, I've tried every solution on the internet.

It is happening with Ubuntu based distros only. Fedora and arch-based distros give no error.

My hardware is perfectly fine.

output is
The installer encountered an error copying file to the hard disk:

[Errno 5] Input/output error

This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.

I've also tried different installation medias(different USB sticks ) and used my phone as a bootable device but no effect
I've checked multiple times that my ubuntu iso file is not corrupt

Comment: That error refers to a hard disk problem or an error with the hardware driving the hard drive. Input/Output errors during filesystem access attempts generally mean hardware issues. Type dmesg and check the last few lines of output. If the disc or the connection to it is failing, it'll be noted there. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39905/input-output-error-when-accessing-a-directory#:~:text=Input%2FOutput%20errors%20during%20filesystem,it'll%20be%20noted%20there.

Comment: thanks for reply
but fedora and  manjaro is installing perfectly

Comment: You'll need to provide the full message (possibly with lines above and/or below) as it could also mean it's an issue with the installation media itself (were there `squashfs` errors on nearby lines)... Did you explore the error messages? (we can't see them), did you verify your ISO prior to write to media? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) or your write to media? as we cannot know unless told.

Comment: You didn't provide release details, so I didn't provide the verification links for your media (it varies on release; later releases self-verify however not all provide the answer easily.. the latest release (*hirsute*) requires you to explore logs to see it as it's performed in the background thus doesn't show the result on screen)   Your mention of install other OSes doesn't disprove disk problems also (unless you used `badblocks` & other checks & didn't tell us)

Comment: The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:

[Errno 5] Input/output error

This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.

this was the message @guiverc

Comment: @Aniruddha Please remember to edit your question whenever you're requested additional information, do not just comment. The error clearly says it's the installation media. If all Ubuntu and Debian based attempts of installation were done with the same USB stick and other with a different one then the problem is likely the stick itself. If the same was used for ALL attempt then there's no logical explanation other than you managed to have corrupt images for all but Fedora and Manjaro somehow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I see a message SQUASHFS ERROR:UNABLE TO READ DATA AND PAGE WHILE INSTALLING UBUNTU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236021/why-do-i-see-a-message-squashfs-errorunable-to-read-data-and-page-while-install)

Comment: CD refers to your installation media, meaning you failed to verify your ISO (link I already provided) or you failed to verify the write to your installation media (use the appropriate method for your *unstated* release and/or flavor of Ubuntu).  In my experience, the write to USB media (ie. cheap no-verify) media is most at fault, and checking the logs will make that clear.

Comment: Did you perform the *CD Integrity Check* function for your *unstated* release of Kubuntu ?  where CD refer to any installation media (be it CD, DVD, HDD, SSD, thumb-drive, or whatever media you used).  USB memory sticks are not high-quality devices, they're consumables made to price without any verification hardware built in, so bad writes occur - thus the need to verify the media as per the steps provided for any release of Ubuntu/Kubuntu (again you didn't provide a release so use/check the appropriate method)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu)