# How to install Ubuntu 20.04 alongside windows 11

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

Tried to install ubuntu 20.04 using USB. Choosing the 'Ubuntu' option in the GRUB menu, gives the error "X86/cpu" SGX disables by BIOS".
Choosing the "Ubuntu(safe graphics)" option in the GRUB menu, leads to the error "Check finished: errors found 1 files! You might encounter errors.". Kindly guide as to how to install alongside Windows 11.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I see a message SQUASHFS ERROR:UNABLE TO READ DATA AND PAGE WHILE INSTALLING UBUNTU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236021/why-do-i-see-a-message-squashfs-errorunable-to-read-data-and-page-while-install)

Comment: The error you mention (*file error found*) is the way the error in the duplicate I've tagged is shown before you attempt to install with that media - ie. if you continue; you'll get the errors I talk about in that duplicate.  Did you verify your ISO prior to write to installation media??  as either that failed; or more likely; the write of ISO to your media was faulty!  (in my experience about 5-8% of writes to sandisk media fails [USB flash drives are cheap!] with more failures on cheaper media..]

Comment: Thank you. Checksum is OK. Also tried with a different pen drive. Now the error is different "Unable to find opcode .....". Kindly guide.

Comment: check your uefi/Bios for settings hardware virtualisierung and the second is intel specific  (Software Guard Extensions) Have you annother computer/Notebook to test your install media?

Comment: The install media is working in another old computer. Now I am getting a new error saying "password expiry information changed" and it hangs. Regarding virtualising what setting should I give? And I am unable to find Intel specific setting in BIOS.

Comment: Used an external hard disk, used acpi=off xforcevesa options to boot and also unplugged extra peripheral devices. Now the live USB is booting. Further I tried to do a custom installation with one EFI, boot, swap and root partitions. At the end of installation, a fatal error occurs "grub-install failed". And I am unable to boot into Ubuntu. Kindly guide.

Comment: Used boot repair to get the following output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KmS87TjDJS   Can I go ahead with the boot repair?