# I can't get Kubuntu 23.04 to open from a live USB pen drive

Tags: boot, usb, mount, live-usb, squashfs

After downloading the .iso file and chcked it with MD5, I used Rufus (Windows 10) to make the Live USB flash drive.

When booting from the USB flash drive I get the following message:

> *[ 0.118288] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.*
>
> *BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)*
>
> *Enter 'help' for a list os built-in commands.*
>
> *(initramfs) mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on /filesystem.squashfs failed: Input/output* error
>
> *Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on /filesystem.squashfs*

I also tried a USB flash drive made with LiLi (Windows 10) and I get the same message. And tried a second USB flash drive.

Is there any specific BIOS/UEFI configuration that I must check/set?

Comment: Squashfs IO errors imply you've had a bad write of ISO to your media, assuming the checksum of your downloaded ISO was correct as I understand you checked.   Your installation media (which is a *squashed* *file-system* is corrupt)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I see a message SQUASHFS ERROR:UNABLE TO READ DATA AND PAGE WHILE INSTALLING UBUNTU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236021/why-do-i-see-a-message-squashfs-errorunable-to-read-data-and-page-while-install)

Comment: See also my MEDIA CHECKS answer on this post - https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile   (ie. that answer  is closer to your issue in my opinion; though if it's a VM the error can be caused by invalid settings, inc. insufficient RAM/resources though rarely an issue on actual hardware/metal in my experience)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!

Thanks folks!

I made another USB flash drive and it worked fine.

Seems that I have 2 kind of bad USB flash drives.

The Live version is running well.

SOLVED!!!!